# Trying to Structure BeautifulSoup to Flexibly Scrape Company Annual Reports

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use the United States Securities and Exchange (SEC) database, to look at company financial reports (known as 10k’s) to pull out a list of the executive committee members for each filing.   I am currently using the most recent files for Microsoft (stock ticker: MSFT) and Walmart (stock ticker: WMT).  I know I can look up this information elsewhere on finance websites but I am trying to make a flexible database for personal use.  My issue:

1. The table index position is different in each report, on one company report the table I want may
   be table 38 and on another it may be table 45 so a static index/position count will not work across 
   multiple filings.
2. The specific attributes in each HTML table tag change so I cannot search for a common attribute.  In 
   some cases I find common attributes and sometimes I do not.

I am starting to think I may not be able to automate this due to lack of identifiers that are unique within each file and common across all files.  I've banged my head looking at many Python Webscraping tutorials and videos the last few weeks.  Any suggestions are appreciated, full automation would be ideal so I can loop through multiple filings, partial helps too I'm here to learn.  I might be bumping into trying to automate something that is too diverse.

**Microsoft Link:**

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459019027952/msft-10k_20190630.htm

**Desired Table:**

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%;">
```

**Walmart Link:**

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/104169/000010416919000016/wmtform10-kx1312019.htm

**Desired Table:**

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:10pt;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;text-align:left;">
```

**Code to Count Number of Tables in Each Page:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

chrome_path = r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

#Microsoft
browser.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459019027952/msft-10k_20190630.htm")
msft = browser.page_source
page_msft = BeautifulSoup(msft, 'html.parser')
tables_msft = page_msft.find_all("table")

#Walmart
browser.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/104169/000010416919000016/wmtform10-kx1312019.htm")
wmt = browser.page_source
page_wmt = BeautifulSoup(wmt, 'html.parser')
tables_wmt = page_wmt.find_all("table")

print("MSFT Result Table Count: " + str(len(tables_msft)))
print("Walmart Result Table Count: " + str(len(tables_wmt)))
```

**Results:**

MSFT Result Table Count: 263

Walmart Result Table Count: 258

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Hi can you point out the exact table with a screenshot. The desired table you mentioned in the question applies to all the table elements on the page. So it will be helpful if you provide an exact table with contents

Comment: Hi thank you for trying to help.  The tables are actually too long to paste into here.  I am new to this forum so if there is a better way to share that I am not aware of please let me know.  The easiest way without pasting the entire table would be to search the Microsoft html (view source) for "Satya Nadella" the CEO.  There are five results, the first one is in the table I am seeking.  For the Walmart file a search for "Daniel Bartlett" would yield the table I am looking for (one result).  I appreciate you helping me out!  If this doesn't work I can try a screenshot but it would be large.

Comment: @jamesishere well in short way, you want to extract a specific info from html where the order of it can be changed in other pages? which info you want from this [part](https://imgur.com/B3xrV2N)

Comment: @jamesishere did the below code solve your problem.

Comment: @prakhar-jhudele I have not had time to run the code yet but hope to at some point today.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη Thank you for the response, for that table at this point I would just be looking for the name of the officer and the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you don't need Selenium, requests library will be faster and avoid overhead. So I was able to partially figure out a way to extract the required data. But since the number of columns is different they cannot be combined together(for Microsoft and Walmart).
The below code generates two required dataframe one for Microsoft and one for Walmart. 
You still need to manipulate the column names. The idea is to get the table with td value as 'Age' since it is a unique table data. Let me know if you need some clarifications:-

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


#Microsoft
page = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/789019/000156459019027952/msft-10k_20190630.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html')
resmsft = []
tables_msft = soup.find(text="Age").find_parent("table")
for row in tables_msft.find_all("tr")[1:]:
#    print([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
    if row:
        resmsft.append([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])

non_empty = [sublist for sublist in resmsft if any(sublist)]
df_msft = pd.DataFrame.from_records(non_empty)
df_msft[df_msft==''] = np.nan 
df_msft=df_msft.dropna(axis=1,how='all')


#Walmart
page = requests.get("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/104169/000010416919000016/wmtform10-kx1312019.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html')
#page_wmt = BeautifulSoup(soup, 'html.parser')
tables_wmt = soup.find(text="Age").find_parent("table")
reswmt = []
for row in tables_wmt.find_all("tr")[1:]:
#    print([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
    if row:
        reswmt.append([cell.get_text(strip=True) for cell in row.find_all("td")])
non_empty_wmt = [sublist for sublist in reswmt if any(sublist)]
df_wmt = pd.DataFrame.from_records(non_empty_wmt)
df_wmt[df_wmt==''] = np.nan 
df_wmt=df_wmt.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much I will take a look and see if I understand everything you are doing here and let you know how things go.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This has taught me a lot about scraping Prakhar!  I was able to run the code and am very satisfied.  I am going to continue to try similar things on other documents.  Once again, thank you for taking the time to help me and teach me some new methods for scraping!